# How to TABLESAMPLE with NHibernate?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I want to add a specific SQL to 1 query which will work only on SQL Server. How to do that:

Criteria:

```
        Session
            .CreateCriteria<User>()
            .Add(Expression.Sql("TABLESAMPLE (100 PERCENT)"))
            .SetMaxResults(count)
            .List<User>();
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT
     TOP (6)
      this_.user_id
FROM users this_
WHERE TABLESAMPLE (100 PERCENT)
```

EXPECTED SQL:

```
SELECT
     TOP (6)
      this_.user_id
FROM users this_
TABLESAMPLE (100 PERCENT)
```

The WHERE keyword should no exist. How to do that?

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `ICriteria` abstraction over SQL, if you're going to have plain SQL anyway? Just use `Session.CreateSqlQuery(...)` and use your native query.

It makes no real sense to use the tool just for the sake of using it (and somehow abusing it in this particular case). `ICriteria` is better suited for entity queries, not for database-side operations.

Comment: I have ton of restrictions which are not listed here for simplicity. HQL is also an option.

Comment: OK, so I don't think it is possible to mix NHibernate abstraction with such specific database functions. Maybe stored procedure will be suitable here?

Comment: What about extending Criteria api? Are there any extension points? SP is not an option :(

Comment: @myknow: I was looking for the extension points to FROM query fragment in NH source, but looks like you'll need to provide your own `IEntityPersister` implementation and this is hidden quite deep inside NH - I gave up anyway. You can also see this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/af873d128f67f778